# Localization of Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, localization

I am working on an Android game..
I live in Taiwan but i want to make an English game, i have some problem when using facebook login Dialog is always loaded in Chinese. Is there any way i can change it to English which is the same with the device's language?

Thanks,

Eve

Answer (score 2):

Change the localization string in Facebook when you make the API calls:

> Internationalization Facebook Connect
>   features are available many locales.
>   You can replace the en_US locale
>   specifed above with one of the
>   supported Facebook Locales. For
>   example, to load up the library and
>   trigger dialogs, popups and plugins to
>   be in Hindi (hi_IN), you can load the
>   library from this URL:
>
> http://connect.facebook.net/hi_IN/all.js

So in the Android SDK change any calls to facebook to have the en_US Internationalization tag

If you want to match it to the phone's language then you will need to change the SDK to make a call to the Android system settings and replace the tag appropriately - [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.htmlt](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Comment: I'm using facebook android sdk.
http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

To call the FB login dialog, they use this way.
facebook = new Facebook();
 facebook.authorize(context, applicationId, new String[] {}, new LoginDialogListener());

will call this url, so where should i add the locale.
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
    client_id=...&
    redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback&
    display=touch

Thanks

Comment: It appears as though there is no current support for localization and the graph api that I can find. The method I outlines only works if you redirect the user via the normal facebook login procedure

Answer (score 2):

Make changes in the `facebook-android-sdk-4.0.0/facebook/src/com/facebook/internal/WebDialog.java` file in your facebook sdk.

You need to make changes in the constructor

```
public WebDialog(Context context, String action, Bundle parameters, int theme, OnCompleteListener listener)
```

Add  the code mentioned below in it before

```
Uri uri = Utility.buildUri(
    ServerProtocol.getDialogAuthority(),
    ServerProtocol.getAPIVersion() + "/" + ServerProtocol.DIALOG_PATH + action, parameters
);

//FOR APP SPECIFIC LOCALE
parameters.putString("locale2", context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString());
```

or

```
parameters.putString("locale2", **LOCALE_YOU_WANT_TO_SET**);
```